# Как структурировать код в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

Помню, когда работал на Sublime Text, была возможность чтобы код правильно вставлялся. `<div>` под `<div>`, отступы и т.д.

Как сделать такое на Visual Studio Code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/5045688

Comment: в большинстве случаев `alt+shift+f` должно помогать

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Автоматическое форматирование кода в Visual Studio Code выполняется следующими комбинациями:

- Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Огромное спасибо , наконец то не надо будет в онлайн форматере работать

Answer (score 3):

В дополнении к ответу от @Эникейщик

В настройках можно установить `форматирование при сохранении`

##### Что искать в настройках

1. Или `Editor: Format On Save` в графическом интерфейсе
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Или `editor.formatOnSave` в settings.json
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

##### Предупреждение:

Влючайте данную опцию, если вы точно уверены в своих настройках и используемых форматтерах. При сохранении файлы будут изменены. И это может давать побочные эффекты также для git-веток.